# Fresh airflow server not executing example tasks

Tags: airflow

I recently completed a fresh airflow setup and it has the example DAGs. I tried to execute them, but nothing worked.

I used the [this link](https://www.corbettanalytics.com/installing-airflow-on-ubuntu-18/) to install airflow.

[image: Example Airflow DAG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following. It should work:

1. Check whether the scheduler and webserver are up or not.
2. It appears from the screenshot that the DAG is not in ON State. Scheduler will not recognize in the OFF state.
3. Please mark the first execution as success and trigger for the second time, it should execute.

Comment: 1. everything is up, 2.I want to trigger manually, I don't think so it an issue. 3. Tried this trick :(

Comment: Please try triggering the dag once after enabling the dag to ON state. Tasks will not get initiated when the dag is on OFF state.